# Dynamic Schema for the same table in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table Orders.
Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = "myschema")
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now I want the schema should change dynamically during runtime.
I have two different Schema(public and myschema) in the database(Postgres SQL), both have the same table, but based on the condition it should call the schema.
Is there a way to do it?

This is my JPA class

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * From  secondpublic.orders", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Orders> findAllSecondOrders();

    @Query(value = "SELECT * From public.orders", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Orders> findAllPublicOrders();
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {
    
    @Autowired
    private OrdersRepository ordersRepo;

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;
    
    @GetMapping()
    public List<Orders> getEmployees(@RequestParam String mode) {
        return ordersRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Based on some condition, schema should be variable/dynamic.

@Table(name = "orders", schema = "{myschema}")

Comment: Maybe a `@MappedSuperclass` and two different empty entities that extends `Orders` with two different schema?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called schema based multitenancy. See the Hibernate documentation about how you can configure this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-separate-schema

Answer (score 0):

You could use multitenancy in your project,

A good documentation you can find on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa)

I hope it helps!